# Manually updating Form.Item value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I need to update the value of `Form.Item` manually. I have a custom component, which returns selected value, and want to pass this value to the `Form` for validation and so I can send it.

Is this possible with `antd`?

Here's the simplified code:

```
import { Form } from "antd";
import { FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Child: FC<{
  returnValue: (value: any) => void;
}> = ({ returnValue }): ReactElement => {
  return <input onChange={(e) => returnValue(e.currentTarget.value)} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const { useForm } = Form;
  const [form] = useForm();

  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

  const setNewValue = (newVal: string) => setValue(newVal);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      test
      <Form form={form}>
        <Form.Item
          //value={value} I'm looking form smth like this
        >
          <Child returnValue={setNewValue} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-butterfly-c4ysh?file=/src/App.tsx) is the code sandbox.

Using `<Input>` from `antd` will not work in my case. This is a simplified problem. I have a way more complex component, which behaves in a similar way. The `returnValue` is how I managed to pull the value out of the component.

Comment: you already have the value saved in the state "value" of App component. If you want to check changes in the state "value" you could use useEffect hook as such:

useEffect(() => {
       console.log(value)
    }, [value]);

which would be executed only on changes to "value"

You could also get the all the value of the Form Items with the getFieldsValue({}) or getFieldValue(<fieldname>) properties of the ant design form.

https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance

Comment: Yes. The problem is, I don't see a way to actually assign the value to `Form.Item`'s value. Am I missing something?

Comment: Form.Item has no "value" attribute you could check properties of Form.Item here https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item

Comment: You could use the setFieldsValue({}) funtion of FormInstance to set the values of Form.Item
https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a class based component, this is how you would define a form

```
class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef();
  constructor()
    render(){
      return(
        <Form 
          ref={this.formRef} 
          name="customForm"
        >
          <Form.Item label="Email" name="email">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      )} 
}
```

and this is how you set form.items value

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
       email: this.props.customerData.map((d) => d.email),
    });
   }
```

you can convert the logic for the functional component.

Comment: This was the missing piece. Thanks!